# Air as3 app: One App to house many Apps

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, packaging

I am wondering if it is possible to create a master app or suite or container (not sure what to call it) to house multpile apps? I am working in Flash using as3 and packaging as air.

I am working on creating multiple apps for a company and they would like to have an app that when you click on it, all of the apps the person has downloaded from the company would appear inside of it. Keeping all of that companies apps on your device in one location, easy to find. For example, the kindle app. It is one app on your device that when you click on it, it opens up and displays all of the books you have chosen to download. You click the book you want and it opens up. Any ideas?

I don't want to package all of the apps together because I want the person to be able to choose which apps they want to download. I have no clue where to start on this one.

Sorry if my explanation is kind of confusing but I appreciate any help. Keep in mind I am fairly new at this stuff. Thank you!

Comment: The Kindle example you have can be translated into "an AIR application loading swf files" so each book is not an application but a document instead. In your situation, can you create a master application which actually launches the selected application (among a list of the installed ones) or optionally select a file to open, which will eventually launch the necessary application?

Comment: I am not sure I am following your question. I want a master app that when opened, will display all of the apps that the user has chosen to install on their device from the company. And when they click on a specific app, I want it to open up. I don't really have a preference on how that app is opened, it could launch a code that opens the specified app. I just don't want one single app that contains the code for every possible app we might create because that would be one large file and not give the user the freedom to download what they want.

Answer (score 0):

If your idea is to target iOS then no, you can't. Because it's not allowed to load extra code from anywhere else  but the app's own directory so you have to package everything into one app. Android may be a different story though.

Comment: I plan to have it work across iOS and Android... If it's possible??